# Как в react native выводить в консоль данные?

Tags: react-native

Установил react native. Система windows. Использую android studio. Подскажите пожалуйста где смотреть console.log()

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text, Image, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Modal from "react-native-modal";

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isModalVisible: false,
    datanews: []
  };

  _toggleModal = () => {
    this.setState({ isModalVisible: !this.state.isModalVisible });
  }
  componentWillMount(){
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var arr;
        req.onload = () => {
            arr = req.response;
            this.setState({datanews: arr});
            
        }
        req.open("GET", "https://www.btcnn.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts", true);
        req.responseType = "json";
        req.send();
    }

  render() {
    let obj = this.state.datanews;
    console.debug(obj);
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В системе установлен Google Chrome? При активации Remote JS Debugging должна открыться вкладка в Chrome, в которой открываешь DevTools кнопкой f12 и дальше вкладка Console. Можешь попробовать открыть его самостоятельно, по умолчанию это: http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/